# Exception when parsing int from String after it was sent with Datagram

Tags: java, parsing, integer, datagram

I'm starting to feel real stupid - and hopefully this question's got a simple answer.

I'm trying to send the coordinates of a Point object over UDP. The sending works great:

```
public void send(Point p) throws IOException {
        String data = Integer.toString(p.x) + " " + Integer.toString(p.y);
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(this.remoteHost);
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        sendData = data.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, this.remotePort);
        socket.send(sendPacket);
}
```

And I can receive the data on the other end:

```
byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
this.socket.receive(receivePacket);
```

As you might see I'm sending the String "X Y", for example "329 456". I now need to parse those values to integers, so I can use them on the other end:

```
String[] parts = data.split(" ");
int x = Integer.parseInt(new String(parts[0]));
int y = Integer.parseInt(new String(parts[1]));
```

But this gives me a NumberFormatException on the y integer ("For input string: '456'"). Why? Is there anything I'm missing here? I've been thinking about he actual encoding of the characters send - could that be the reason why Integer won't understand the value?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: have you tried debugging? what is value of `parts[0]` and `parts[1]` before trying parsing to int? may be some extra characters are there

Comment: Print parts[1] and make sure it is an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't take packet length into account when converting packet data to `String`.

You should do it as follows:

```
String data = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
```

Also, it would be better to specify character encoding explicitly when sending and receiving the message, to prevent issues when machines have different default encodings:

```
sendData = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
...
String data = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength(), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading data in this way?

```
String data = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
```